# -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: in Google currency converter in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need live currency rates. I am using a Google API available in the URL

```
http:://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?INR
```

Whenever am hitting that URL using json parsing, then response data getting nil. I am not getting what is the exact error in that code

```
#define openexchangeURl @"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?INR"

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:openexchangeURl]];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
values =[responseString JSONValue];
```

Comment: The second ? in the query string should be a red flag. Double check your URL.

Comment: can pls give sample code for how can to parse url and also {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "54.0336089 Indian rupees",error: "",icc: true} this data after hit that url i need only that values is 54.0336089

Comment: Sounds like a different question.  Are you saying that you are no longer getting a nil response?

Comment: I've checked the url it is showing correctly in online json parser but it is not getting parsed by json library so I think it is showing null in response but the response string is showing correctly

Comment: yes right now am get response data in same format like {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "54.0336089 Indian rupees",error: "",icc: true} how can get from 54.0336089 value ..any idea

Comment: While I'm trying to parse using "SBJSON" it is showing the error "-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object key string expected\" UserInfo=0x104d1dfb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Object key string expected}"
)"

Comment: And with "NSJSONSerialization" the error is "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 1.) UserInfo=0x7561050 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 1.}"

Answer (score 1):

This will get you live rates:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=INR&q=1"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *parsedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
    CGFloat value = [parsedDict[@"rate"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Value: %f", value);
}];
```

The JSON response from that api looks like this:

```
{
  to: "INR",
  rate: 54.8245614,
  from: "USD",
  v: 54.8245614
}
```

Your original request didn't have an `NSURLConnection` and the response was not valid JSON (did not have double-quoted values for each item in the hash).